# Where are permissions stored in DB?

Tags: 6, users

I'm looking at the DB but can't find where the permissions are stored.

On the Admin page the permissions can be saved at `/admin/user/permissions`

But where this data is saved in the DB?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Permissions are stored in the `permission` table.

The table stores a comma-separated list of permissions that are enabled for each role, by role ID, which links back to the `role` table.

The `users_roles` table makes the final link between users and the roles assigned to them.

Comment: In drupal 7  there is no permission  table. Can you explain where is it.

Comment: It's `role_permission` in D7 @Fawwad

Comment: Where is it in D8, if you don't mind? @Clive

Comment: @TonyStecca In configuration https://stackoverflow.com/a/59641998/1941773